# Remove trailing substring from String in Java

Tags: java, string

I am looking to remove parts of a string if it ends in a certain string.

An example would be to take this string: `"am.sunrise.ios@2x.png"`

And remove the `@2x.png` so it looks like: `"am.sunrise.ios"`

How would I go about checking to see if the end of a string contains `"@2x.png"` and remove it?

Comment: Check out the `substring` and `endsWith` methods from the `String` class

Comment: It's well documented: [String#endsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Do you want to replace always `@2x.png` or any substring which starts with `@` till end?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could check the `lastIndexOf`, and if it exists in the string, use `substring` to remove it:

```
String str = "am.sunrise.ios@2x.png";
String search = "@2x.png";

int index = str.lastIndexOf(search);
if (index > 0) {
    str = str.substring(0, index);
}
```

Comment: `String.lastIndexOf` can find the substring anywhere in the string, not just at the end. You should check `str.endsWith(suffix)` instead, and you can then inline the call to `lastIndexOf`.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have a string initialized as `String file = "am.sunrise.ios@2x.png";`.

```
if(file.endsWith("@2x.png"))
    file = file.substring(0, file.lastIndexOf("@2x.png"));
```

The `endsWith(String)` method returns a boolean determining if the string has a certain suffix. Depending on that you can replace the string with a substring of itself starting with the first character and ending before the index of the character that you are trying to remove.

Comment: The index cannot be -1 as the string is already checked to end with "@2x.png"

Comment: `lastIndexOf` is more correct since we need to remove the specified string only at the end. `indexOf` returns the first occurence of the specified string but in this case, we need the **last occurence** of that specified string. `.endsWith("@2x.png")` gives us the assurance that the `lastIndexOf` is actually **@2x.png**. @Pshemo

Answer (score 9):

```
private static String removeSuffixIfExists(String key, String suffix) {
    return key.endswith(suffix)
        ? key.substring(0, key.length() - suffix.length())
        : key; 
    }
}

String suffix = "@2x.png";
String key = "am.sunrise.ios@2x.png";

String output = removeSuffixIfExists(key, suffix);
```

Comment: IMHO, this should be the accepted answer. It is the most efficient solution : the suffix is matched only once, contrary to the other solutions based on endsWith()+lastIndexOf().

Comment: Moreover, the currently accepted solution may delete way more than the suffix...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generally remove entire content of string from `@` till end you can use

```
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("@.*","");
```

where `@.*` is regex ([regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)) representing substring starting with `@` and having any character after it (represented by `.`) zero or more times (represented by `*`).

In case there will be no `@xxx` part your string will be unchanged.

---

If you want to change only this particular substring `@2x.png` (and not substirng like `@3x.png`) while making sure that it is placed at end of your string you can use

```
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("@2x\\.png$","");
```

where

- `$` represents end of string
- `\\.` represents `.` literal (we need to escape it since like shown earlier `.` is metacharacter representing *any* character)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    String word = "am.sunrise.ios@2x.png";

    word = word.replace("@2x.png", "");

    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Comment: This does not remove that string from the end. The string for example could be `"@2x.png@2x.png"` and that should result to `"@2x.png"` not "" as this would tamper with the objective of the asker.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. I just ran the code again and the output was...... "am.sunrise.ios" I'm not very experienced at this so if I'm missing something then please help me understand.

Comment: Your solution removes "@2x.png" from the string. However it does not check if it is at the end of the string, as it will be removed regardless of being at the beginning of the string

Answer (score 1):

Since I was trying to do this on an ArrayList of items similarly styled I ended up using the following code:

```
    for (int image = 0; image < IBImages.size(); image++) {
        IBImages.set(image, IBImages.get(image).split("~")[0].split("@")[0].split(".png")[0]);
    }
```

If I have a list of images with the names

```
[am.sunrise.ios.png, am.sunrise.ios@2x.png, am.sunrise.ios@3x.png, am.sunrise.ios~ipad.png, am.sunrise.ios~ipad@2x.png]
```

This allows me to split the string into 2 parts.
For example, "am.sunrise.ios~ipad.png" will be split into "am.sunrise.ios" and "~ipad.png" if I split on "~". I can just get the first part back by referencing [0]. Therefore I get what I'm looking for in one line of code.

Note that ***image*** is "am.sunrise.ios~ipad.png"

Answer (score 0):

You could use String.split():

```
public static void main(String [] args){
  String word = "am.sunrise.ios@2x.png";
  String[] parts = word.split("@");
  if (parts.length == 2) {
    System.out.println("looks like user@host...");
    System.out.println("User: " + parts[0]);
    System.out.println("Host: " + parts[1]);
  }
}
```

Then you haven an array of Strings, where the first element contains the part before "@" and the second element the part after the "@".

Answer (score -1):

Combining the answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28387960/4607733) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28387934/4607733):

```
String str = "am.sunrise.ios@2x.png";
String search = "@2x.png";

if (str.endsWith(search)) {
  str = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(search));
}
```

Comment: This wastes performance for searching the string twice.